# Cannot get the model binding in the controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following form in the cshtml file:

```
<form action="@Url.Action(controllerAction, controller, new { area = area })" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="OnBeginForm" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="OnSuccess" data-ajax-failure="OnFailure" method="post">
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-error" id="errorContainer" style="display:none;">
            <span id="errorList">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@Model.Id" />

            <div class="box-body">

                <h4>
                    Delete City '@Model.Code'?
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" onclick="controlSubmit(this,this.form);" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>
        <a data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-right:15px;  cursor:pointer; vertical-align:-webkit-baseline-middle">Cancel</a>
    </div>
}
</form>
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(CitiesDataModel model)
{
    log.Info("Deleting City...");
    log.Info(model);
}
```

My model:

```
public class CitiesDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string IdEnc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

The form is submitted successfully and i get the logs in the controller but the model  is empty. Why is this happen?

Comment: How can we possibly help without even knowing what `CitiesDataModel` looks like?

Comment: I added the model

Comment: Hi @pikk, whether the problem solved or not? If not, try to use F12 developer tools to check the form elements, whether the name and value property is correct? Besides, from your code, it seems that you are using `controlSubmit()` function to submit the form, can you share this part of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add _ViewImports.cshtml?

Please check asp-for is using the tagHelper. Otherwise, it'll not map the model.
Add the line in your _ViewImports.cshtml file

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
```